# my span is above others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an animation with several span, I want them all to be separated and can be read completely.

```js
window.horizontalScroller = function($elem) {
  var left = parseInt($elem.css("left"));
  var temp = -1 * $('#horizontalScroller > div').height();
  if (left < temp) {
    left = $('#horizontalScroller').height()
    $elem.css("left", left);
  }
  $elem.animate({
    left: (parseInt(left) - 60)
  }, 11000, function() {
    window.horizontalScroller($(this))
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#horizontalScroller > span").each(function() {
    $(this).css("left", i);
    i += 60;
    window.horizontalScroller($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
#horizontalScroller {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#horizontalScroller>span {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizontalScroller">
  <span>100 characteres</span>
  <span>110 characteres</span>
  <span>120 characteres</span>
  <span>130 characteres</span>
  <span>140 characteres</span>
  <span>150 characteres</span>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I want them all to be separated"* - What do you mean by "separated"? On separate lines? Or with horizontal space between them? Or do you want each span to stay in place and just have the text scroll within it? Or...?

Comment: space beetween...  http://jsfiddle.net/rjogdygc/

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your `$(document).ready` to be like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#horizontalScroller > span").each(function () {
          $(this).css("left", i);
          i += 100;
          window.horizontalScroller($(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to separate them then you can just increse the `i`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#horizontalScroller > span").each(function () {
        $(this).css("left", i);
        i += 110;
        window.horizontalScroller($(this));
    });
});
```

But the whole animation breaks after some time, so I recommend a different  approach or some heavy optimization.